# AutoStart Application Using System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, wpf, system.diagnostics

I am going to install my installer which is created from Visual Studio install shield using `System.Diagnostics.process`.
 When I install the installer directly, I can see that the installer automatically launches.

But when I install the same installer using `System.Diagnostics.process`, the app is not launched automatically.

How can I automatically launch my app by using the `System.Diagnostics.process`?

I am using the following code to install it by using `process`:

```
string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.FileName = tempPath + "myAppexe.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "/s /v/qn";

if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
{
    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
}
```

Comment: did you take care of admin previlages for the app which invokes this `System.Diagnostics.Process`?

Comment: Yes .It is using Admin Privilleges